# Troubleshooting Issues with Laravel Broadcast Routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-websockets

The routing is not functioning as expected, and regardless of the processing in private channels, it consistently returns successful authorization.

```
 "laravel/framework": "^10.10"
 "beyondcode/laravel-websockets": "^1.14.1",
 "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.2.1",
```

```
Broadcast::channel('users.1', function (User $user, int $userId) {
    return false;
});
```

```
testapp: connection id 288426454.774642121 received message: {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"auth":"websocketkey:0903fc7ae38e6df122f7f38afea7111afa4c498d390498f01bbce50129a171a8","channel":"private-users.1"}}.
Connection id 288426454.774642121 sending message {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","channel":"private-users.1"}
```

Lowered all possible versions, googled, read documentation and studied the issue on git